# Need to generate a client and project code for a client and project in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):

    client_name=models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    client_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=None, null=True)
    company=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    finance_contact_email=models.EmailField(max_length=25,default=None)
    business_purpose=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,default=None)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    emergency_contact=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,default=None)
    website=models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True)
    comments=models.TextField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    start_Date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10,null=True)
    end_Date=models.DateField(max_length=10,null=True)
 
    class Meta:
        
        db_table ='Client'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.client_name)

#Project model
class Project(models.Model):

    project_code = models.CharField(primary_key=False, editable=False, max_length=10,default=None,null=True)
    #client_project_code = models.CharField(primary_key=False, editable=False, max_length=10,default=None,null=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,default=None)
    client_code = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="Client5",default=None, null=True) # need to get the client code instead of name but the name should be returned in client model
    client= models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="Client1",default=None)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='users',default=None)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.TextField()                                      #dropdown
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    technical_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    delivery_head_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    class Meta:
        
        db_table ='Project'


    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            max = Project.objects.aggregate(id_max=Max('project_code'))['id_max']
            self.project_code = "{}{:03d}".format('', max if max is not None else 1)
        super().save(*kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(str(self.client_code), str(self.project_code))
```

As per the above code I created a client code in client model and I need to combine the client code plus the  project code which is auto generated in the project code field itself or in a new field.
for ex: client code: ICN and project code: ICN001.
And one main thing is i want the client name to be returned in the client model and i need to link the client code from the client model to the project, I was stuck on that method like how to return it ?

note: the changes and the fields needs to be reflected in the django admin portal.

Updated code after the answer:

```
class Project(models.Model):

    project_code = models.CharField(primary_key=False, editable=False, max_length=10,default=None,null=True)
    #client_project_code = models.CharField(primary_key=False, editable=False, max_length=10,default=None,null=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,default=None)
    #client_code = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="Client5",default=None, null=True)
    client= models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="Client1",default=None)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='users',default=None)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.TextField()                                      #dropdown
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    technical_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    delivery_head_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    class Meta:
        
        db_table ='Project'

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            max = Project.objects.aggregate(id_max=Max('project_code'))['id_max']
            self.project_code = "{}{:03d}".format('', max if max is not None else 1)
        super().save(*kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.client is not None:
            return f'{self.client.client_code}{self.project_code}'
        else:
            return self.project_code
```

As per the answer I updated the code and removed the client code field as it is a duplicate column of client and when i tried to entry details without the client code field iam getting an error as "ValueError at /admin/App/project/add/
Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'". Can you please help me to solve this error?

screenshot of Traceback:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can work with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.client_code is not None:
            return f'{self.client_code.client_code}{self.project_code}'
        else:
            return self.project_code
```

But it makes not much to give your `ForeignKey` to the `Client` the name `client_code`: this will return a `Client` object, not its name, nor its code. `client` thus is thus probably a better choice than <s>`client_code`</s>.

Comment: It is throwing an ValueError at /admin/App/project/add/
Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str' while the removed the client code field and tried to submit. I have updated the code, can you please help me to solve the probelm

Comment: @vinothkumar: add the full traceback.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot

Comment: `project_code` is a string, hence it is `self.project_code = "{:3}".format(int(max) if max is not None else 1)`

Comment: its is getting posted but the project code is generated as 1 not as 001 or 002 which i need on that format, is there anything need to be changed for that?
One more thing can i omit that client code column for not entrying it while posting a new request

Comment: @vinothkumar: `self.project_code = "{:03d}".format(int(max) if max is not None else 1)`

Comment: thanks it works!! but one more thing as said above is there any way to restrict the client_code column and display this same result or is there any way to display the client_code field value from the client model to project model? As now the client and client_code column displays the client_name value in the client model.

Comment: @vinothkumar: that is because you use `self.client_name` in the `__str__` of the `Client` model.

Comment: yes but i need client name in the client field of Client model and i need client code in the client_code of client model. Is that possible?

Comment: @vinothkumar: no, especially since your `client_code` field is *not* the `client_code` or `client_name` of the `Client`, it is a `Client` object...

Comment: yeah i understood, but is there any way to display the client code value of client model in project model client code other than the return type. As i want it to take both client name values and client code values in project model/

Comment: @vinothkumar: you use `self.client_code.client_code`, self.client_code` is a `Client` object, so you can use `self.client_code.client_name` to access the name of the client, and thus use `self.client_code.foo` to access the `.foo` attribute of that `Client` object.

Comment: i was stating that in the field client_code = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="Client8", default=None,null = True) can i take the values of client code entered in the client model as keeping the return type as client_name itself?